# zend locale page not found

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework

I have been given a task to clone the website www.guilherminashoes.com to another hoster under another domain www.guilherminashoesna.com.

Everything works fine except when I click on the link to translate the page to English. I get page not found.

The link that is being called when clicking on ' ENG ' is:

```
http://guilherminashoesna.com/site.php/locale/index/lang/en/url/http%3A%2F%2Fguilherminashoesna.com%2Fsite.php%2F
```

The code of the site.php is as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

try {

    // Define path to application directory
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/private/application'));

    // Define application environment
    defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

    // Ensure library/ is on include_path
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'))));

    /** Zend_Application */
    require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

    // Create application, bootstrap, and run
    $application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

    $application->bootstrap()->run();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

This feature works perfectly fine on www.guilherminashoes.com but does not work on www.guilherminashoesna.com any ideas what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I have accidently solved this myself.... all I have do to was to call this URL:

```
    http://guilherminashoesna.com/site.php/locale/index/lang/en/url/
```

Instead of:

```
    http://guilherminashoesna.com/site.php/locale/index/lang/en/url/http%3A%2F%2Fguilherminashoesna.com%2Fsite.php%2F
```